# Independence of a finite number of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, measurable-functions

Let's fix the probability spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',P')$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}'$ is a sigma algebra of $\Omega'$.

Consider $(E_1,\varepsilon_1),\dots,(E_n,\varepsilon_n)$ to be measurable spaces (namely $\varepsilon_i$ is a sigma algebra of $E_i$).

Now let's fix $X_1\colon \Omega \to E_1,\dots,X_n\colon \Omega \to E_n$ random variables such that $X_i$ is $(\mathcal{F},\varepsilon_i)$-measurable with $i=1,\dots,n$, (namely $\forall \,A \in \varepsilon_i \quad X_i^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$).

Now fix $Y_1\colon \Omega' \to E_1,\dots,Y_n\colon \Omega' \to E_n$ random variables such that $Y_i$ is $(\mathcal{F}',\varepsilon_i)$-measurable.

Moreover suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent (namely given $A_1 \in \varepsilon_1,\dots,A_n \in \varepsilon_n$ then $P(X_1 \in A_1,\dots,X_n \in A_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \in A_i)$).

Suppose even that given $A_1 \in \varepsilon_1,\dots,A_n \in \varepsilon_n$ then $P(X_1 \in A_1,\dots,X_n \in A_n)=P'(Y_1 \in A_1,\dots,Y_n \in A_n)$.

**Then my question: is it true that $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are independent too?**

I already know that when $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are discrete (namely their image is at most countable) and real (endowed with Borel sigma algebra), then this result holds. But is it true even in this general context?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I've thought about this and I think that the answer is not in general.

Comment: Yes? Since $\varepsilon_i$ are sigma algebras, you can pick $A_{i'} =. E_{i'}$ for $i' \neq i$ to get $P'(Y_i \in A_i) = P(X_i \in A_i)$, and so combining the last two equalities in your post should work? I am uncertain as to whether I am missing something, but I don't think so?

Comment: We have to consider EVERY choice of $A_i \in \varepsilon_i$ in order to obtain the independence of $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$. Again, in general we don't necessary have that $P(X_i \in A_i)=P'(Y_i \in A_i)$. Thank you the same.